# Can I still mention a project as research project if it was/will not be published in my cv for graduate studies application?

Tags: graduate-admissions, cv, research-undergraduate, projects

I have done several projects with novel approaches to some problems during my computer science undergraduate studies. Some are course projects but still novel algorithms. These projects have not been published as a paper/conference due to non state of the art results/time constraints etc.

Can I still put them as research projects in the "university projects" section of my CV? I have the code publicly available on github and can also share the reports for the same on github. I also have a separate publication section so published and unpublished work is separate.

I am creating my CV for graduate school admission for masters in computer science (research/thesis based programs)

Comment: Is this for study in India, or elsewhere?

Comment: If you have done some research to get those projects done , you can definitely classify them as research projects.

Comment: @Buffy elsewhere (North america)

Answer (score 2):

There is (usually) no fixed form for a CV. If you think these projects are relevant to people evaluating your admission request, then you can put them into your CV. Make sure that people can easily find your github projects by providing clickable links and make sure that you are not embarrassed by what they find. At the very least, have a good ReadMe file. Remember also that a CV that is too long will/might not be read with the same care as a normal one.